# Invalid hooks call when using widget built with preact inside react app

Tags: reactjs, typescript, babeljs, preact

I am building a library in preact for use with preact apps and widgets. When I install my library with npm into a preact app it works no problem. However, I also have a widget built in preact where I use the library and then I load that widget into a react app and I get two errors: one is the 'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '__H')' and the other is 'preact Uncaught Error: Hook can only be invoked from render methods.'. I've read many posts how to fix this issue with react but I am not sure how to solve this when it is a widget being embedded.

------EDIT------

As requested, here is the link to my repo: https://github.com/ChristopherHButler/preact-leaflet

I've seen some issues that talk about whether preact should be a peer dependency in the `package.json` but the library would not work when I tried that.

And I've copied out the code from the file I am getting the error in below:

```
import { h, RefObject, ComponentChildren } from 'preact';
import { useState } from 'preact/hooks';
import * as Leaflet from 'leaflet';
import 'leaflet/dist/leaflet.css';

import { MapProvider } from '../contexts/MapContext';
import { Map } from './Map';

interface MapContainerProps {
  ref?: RefObject<HTMLDivElement>;
  center: Leaflet.LatLngExpression;
  zoom: number;
  children?: ComponentChildren;
  containerId?: string;
  options?: Leaflet.MapOptions;
  height?: string;
  style?: h.JSX.CSSProperties | undefined;
}

export const MapContainer = ({
  ref,
  center,
  zoom,
  children,
  containerId = 'map',
  options = {},
  height = '400px',
  style = {},
}: MapContainerProps): h.JSX.Element => {

  const [map, setMap] = useState<Leaflet.Map | null>(null);
  
  return (
    <div ref={ref} id={containerId} style={{ height, ...style }}>
      <Map containerId={containerId} setMap={setMap} options={{ ...options, center, zoom }} />
      <MapProvider map={map}>
        {children}
      </MapProvider>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Here is my tsconfig:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
      "target": "es5",
      "lib": [
        "dom",
        "dom.iterable",
        "es2017",
        "esnext"
      ],
      "allowJs": true, // Allow JavaScript files to be compiled
      "skipLibCheck": true, // Skip type checking of all declaration files
      "esModuleInterop": true,  // Disables namespace imports (import * as fs from "fs") and enables CJS/AMD/UMD style imports (import fs from "fs")
      "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true, // Allow default imports from modules with no default export
      "strict": true, // Enable all strict type checking options
      "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true, // Disallow inconsistently-cased references to the same file.
      "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true, // Report errors for fallthrough cases in switch statement
      "module": "esnext", // Specify module code generation
      "moduleResolution": "node", // Resolve modules using Node.js style
      "resolveJsonModule": true, // Include modules imported with .json extension
      "isolatedModules": true, // Warn you if you write certain code that can’t be correctly interpreted by a single-file transpilation process.
      // "noEmit": false, // Do not emit compiler output files like JavaScript source code, source-maps or declarations. This allows another tool (Babel) to handle converting the TypeScript file to a file which can run inside a JavaScript environment.
      "jsx": "preserve", // Support JSX in .tsx files
      "jsxFactory": "h", // Changes the function called in .js files when compiling JSX Elements using the classic JSX runtime.
      "jsxFragmentFactory": "Fragment",
      "jsxImportSource": "preact",
      "declaration": true, // This tells TypeScript to emit an .d.ts definitions file along with your compiled JavaScript, which is what TypeScript will use for type checking.
      "outDir": "./dist", // The javascript will be compiled to the dist folder.
      // "experimentalDecorators": true,
      "strictPropertyInitialization": false

  },
  "include": [
      "src"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    ".parcel-cache",
    "demo",
    "dist",
    "node_modules",
  ]
}
```

And .babelrc:

```json
{
  "plugins": [
    ["@babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx", { "pragma": "h", "pragmaFrag": "Fragment" }]
  ],
  "presets": [
    "@babel/env",
    ["@babel/typescript", { "jsxPragma": "h" }]
  ]
}
```

Comment: Where's the code?

Comment: Sorry about that. I realise it was not a well formed question but because it is so complex I wasn't sure what code I should include. The library repo is public but the widget that uses it is private.

Comment: Sounds like you need `preact/compat`

Comment: Nothing about this indicates needing `preact/compat` at all. OP, you probably want to import `preact/debug` and re-check the errors. It looks more like a Parcel issue and using a hook in a wrong location.

Comment: It’s a very difficult issue to debug because there are three code sources here: the library code, the widget code and the host page. I apologize for the poorly formed question but I was just hoping someone was familiar with the error. I have seen issues with parcel perhaps not bundling correctly but again, difficult to prove and I’m not sure changing bundlers is even an option.

Comment: Like I said, import `preact/debug` into your app to help track it down. It's a common error but there's a lot of surface area for it and you've only provided a small piece of your total application. No one can help with the little information you've provided. Have you looked at Preact's bug tracker? Lot of surface area for triggering that, unless you're willing to share a full, minimal reproduction, best bet is going down the list and evaluating.

Comment: Thanks for the advice rschristian but yes, I have been through all of that. I was posting as a last resort. I have also tried preact/debug.

Comment: morganney I'm curious why you suggest I need preact/compat? Any reason for suggest this?

Comment: @cbutler Did you ever find a solution for this? I'm grappling with the very same issue.